# Intuition for why a convex set with empty interior lies in an affine set

Tags: convex-analysis

In Section 2.5.2 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), the authors claim that

> a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with empty interior must lie in an affine set of dimension less than $n$.

Can someone provide some intuitive explanations of what this means?

Comment: Added to [The List](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convex set contains the line segment between any two points therein. If it is not contained in an affine subspace, it contains an $n$-simplex.